# Bash: remove everything before a certain char

Tags: bash, shell

I have mp3 files of the form "Artist - Song.mp3" I create a directory for the artist, strip the artist's name from the mp3, and move the mp3 into the artist directory. Everything except for stripping the artist's name works.

```
#!bin/bash
for f in *.mp3
do
  artist="${f%-*}"                   #works
  song="${f%*-}"                     #Should work but it doesn't
  mkdir -m 700 ~/home/music/$artist; 
  mv "$song" ~/home/music/$artist    
  echo "artist: $artist"
  echo "song: $song"
done
```

Comment: Use `#`, not `%`, if you want to keep the suffix: `song="${f#*-}"`

Comment: Also note that the spaces are preserved: `artist='Artist '; song=' Song.mp3'`.

Comment: Sample file name and desired output would be nice.

Comment: `${f%*-}` will only have any effect if the name ends in a `-`, and it'll remove **absolutely everything** before that point. Maybe you want `${f#*-}` instead?